# Are multi-level :not selectors possible in CSS / JS querySelector?

Tags: css

I have found many examples explaining how to use multiple :not selectors on an individual element. However, so far I have been unable to find any examples that use :not selectors on different levels within a single selection path in CSS / JS querySelector.
For example, given a HTML structure of:

```
<div class="anything_except_ignore">
    <input type="text" id="a" />
    <input type="hidden" id="b" />
</div>
<div class="ignore">
    <input type="text" id="c" />
</div>
```

I wish to select JUST input#a.
I have tried the following in JS and it does not seem to work:

```
var elems = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.ignore) input:not([type='hidden'])");
```

In this case it appears the first :not selector is ignored (so in the above example both input#a AND input#c are selected.

Have I made a mistake in the syntax or is this approach not possible to use :not selectors in this way to select just input#a?

I can work around this by looking a parent class in JS once the elements are selected, but I'd rather do it properly at the selector stage.

---UPDATE--- as suggested in one of the answers, my mistake was in not understanding that other DIVs further up the DOM can fulfil the :not(.ignore) criteria and so the input under the div.ignore element IS selected. If I remove other DIVs then the requested logic does seem to work as proved by this test:

```js
var res="",elems = document.querySelectorAll("div:not(.ignore) input:not([type='hidden'])");
for(var i=0;i<elems.length;i++){
    res = res + elems[i].id + "\n";
}
alert(res);
```

```html
<div class="anything_except_ignore">
  <div>
    <input type="text" id="aa" value="a"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="bb" value="b"/>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="anything_except_ignore2">
  <span>
    <input type="text" id="dd" value="d"/>
    <input type="hidden" id="ee" value="e"/>
  </span>
</div>
<div class="ignore">
    <input type="text" id="cc" value="c"/>
</div>
```

Sorry for any confusion, but at least this helps clarify how it should work as I could find no other examples of this in my searching.

---CONCLUSION---
As far as I can tell I have to either:

- make sure that my inputs are always immediate children of the div I want to check and use the ">" syntax
- after selection of all non-hidden inputs, use JS to check up the DOM tree of each, to check the class name of all DIVs up the tree.

If there is a better querySelector way to solve this particular issue then I'd love to hear it.

Comment: Hi LGSon, sorry, yes that was a typo in the example (now corrected), but the example was just to illustrate the issue, that typo was not causing the problem as it was not that I was testing. I will build a fiddle to show the issue/test here now. The input is not always a child, so I can't use ">".

Comment: FYI, if you will have an unknown amount of nested `div` and the class you want to ignore is the top parent and the target is a deep descendant, you won't be able to target those with the `not()`, and that is because the `:not(.class)` will apply to any `div`, no matter its nested level.

Comment: LGSon: Yes, that is the issue - a div further up fulfils the :not criteria. I had misunderstood how this works. Also suggested by 04FS's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common misunderstanding of how `:not` works in combination with other selectors.

Let me guess, there are actually more `div` elements than you have shown us, around these elements …?

`div:not(.ignore)` is not “ignored”, but the condition is just fulfilled by a different element than you thought - by some `div` element further up the tree. The space in between the two partial selectors is the *descendant* selector, so *every* `input:not([type='hidden'])` element that has a `div` ancestor that doesn’t have the class `ignore` *anywhere* above it in the DOM tree, matches the full selector.

If you change your selector to `div:not(.ignore) > input:not([type='hidden'])`, this would only select such input fields if their immediate *parent* is a `div` without that class.

Comment: This indeed was the issue. Thank you for clearing this up. As you say, I was expecting, wrongly, that if the :not criteria was fulfilled it would exclude the sub-element, when in fact there was a DIV further up the tree that was not of class "ignore" and therefore the input under the div.ignore still met the criteria. My issue is that the div.ignore might not be the immediate parent, so I can't use the ">" syntax. I will just have to either stick with my JS workaround (which checks ids of parents going up 2 or 3 levels for each selected input).

Comment: Can you maybe select the DIV elements that you need to check for these fields first? If those are all on the same level in a common parent, something like `#parent > div:not(.ignore)` could get all of them, and then you can loop over those and call `querySelectorAll("input:not([type='hidden'])")` on each one inside the loop … that should get you the relevant fields only, without having to check X levels up manually.

Comment: 04FS: Nice idea, but I can't guarantee that the .ignore divs are all at the same level and would like to make the solution generic. I think I'll stick with checking parentNode classes - it isn't that much hassle.